# feature requests regarding sockpuppet accounts to circumvent suspension

Tags: feature-request

1. Delete all posts by the sockpuppet when its account is merged with the suspended one. This should be a sign that what he does is absolutely useless. The posts shouldn't be there in the first place.
2. Restart the suspension counter at each breach. So if an account is suspended on 1 January for 12 months, and the user creates a sockpuppet to log in on 1 December of that year, the suspension period should be extended to 1 December of the next year.

You may not agree with 1), because the answer may be useful anyway. In that case there's no point in suspending, because you would prevent that user to post useful answers. Next, the user in question doesn't post good answers anyway (last 2 days: 5 upvotes, 15 downvotes). Next, if the sockpuppet wouldn't post an answer, someone else will. We have many competent users always willing to help.

Comment: You have my upvote because the overall idea is good although the implementation of part 1 I do not agree with in a general case.

Answer (score 4):

This mostly already matches our method.

1. We only do this if the sock puppetting becomes overly common. Deleting content is against the SE ideal. The contect does not give the user any gain if they are suspended, even with 10000 upvotes they still have no rights on the site. In cases of serial sock puppetry we will start deleting but this is a special case and will be decided between the community moderators and SE community managers.
2. This is standard, but not just resetting the term but extending it. The amount is up to the moderators. Currently you are looking at a user whom is just causing problems and a mod team waiting for the election so that they have the man power to keep up. My standard action here was, merge one sock. Second sock results in suspension lengthening.

The result of case 2 tells the user, sure, make socks to keep getting rep, you will never ever see the rep if you keep doing it.

Comment: Hi Kortuk. Thanks for the useful reply, as usual.